# how do you keep a feature branch up to date with the master branch and vice-versa

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-push, git-pull

Here is my use-case. I have 2 branches

- master (foo)
- beginner-working-on-this (bar)

foo which is an experienced git user works on `master`, while bar who works on `beginner-working-on-this` is a git beginner who doesn't want to handle merging and stuff. foo handles merging unto the master branch and updates bar's branch when something new is in master. (we would like to preserve commit messages)

so foo does `git checkout beginner-working-on-this` , then to be able to preserve commit messages and update bar's branch `git rebase master` . then foo updates the master branch `git merge master`. Now when bar pulls `git pull` on his branch. He gets an error `no tracking information for current branch`

What should bar do from here?

Comment: Why are you doing a `rebase` followed by a `merge`; the `merge` is redundant? The best course of action here is for *bar* to do the rebase himself.

Comment: 'bar' should probably talk to 'foo' for advice on the workflow, and 'foo' should probably be doing rebase rather than merges.  I kind of blame 'foo' here for not coaching 'bar'.  'foo' who is on master, should probably not do 'git merge master', as it should always be up to date.

Comment: We need more information to solve this problem. Is it possible to provide the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`? Also, are foo and bar using one or more remote repos, or are they actually sharing the same local repo?

Comment: Does bar have a remote repo set up to `git pull` from? What is the output if bar does `git remote -v`?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good workflow to have bar update foo's branch by rebasing it, unless foo actually rebases bar's local branch. The reason is that if foo is rebasing the remote branch `<remote>/beginner-working-on-this`, then bar will be forced to re-sync his work with this changed history, which will be difficult for a beginner.

> bar who works on `beginner-working-on-this` is a git beginner who doesn't want to handle merging and stuff.

Bar should really learn how to merge in Git, along with all the other "stuff". Merging happens a lot with Git workflows, Git is designed to make merging really easy. I highly recommend the [**FREE** online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book), especially chapters 1-3, and 6-6.5. Bar should also learn how to `rebase`, both interactively and non-interactively.